# Unable to activate the Apex Language Server - undefined

Tags: apex

[image: Apex Language server -undefied]

[{
"resource": "/ApexLSP",
"owner": "apex",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Unable to activate the Apex Language Server - undefined",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 1
}]

Comment: There's not enough information here. We can't read your mind, see your screen, or log into your org, so you need to _include lots of detail_ when asking questions on this site. Otherwise, we're not going to be able to know what your issue is or how to possibly fix it.

Comment: My best guess is that this `ApexLSP` file isn't an Apex class, and you don't have anything in your project. Hard to tell with so little information. A brief search turned up [this official troubleshooting page with a section on the Language Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/troubleshooting#activate-the-apex-language-server).  We're also not an official part of Salesforce here, so if it is actually an issue with the language server itself then [opening an issue on github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues) is probably the way to go.

Comment: I got the same issue today for first time, and not sure where to start either given VSC and extensions hasnt changed at all in 24 hours.

Comment: Ditto for me, since a few days: Unable to activate the Apex Language Server [Ln 1, Col 1]. Could this be related to the Winter'24 release on sandboxes that happened recently?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Reminder to people coming to this question: "I'm having this problem too" is not an answer to the question. Stackexchange sites (like this one) aren't really suited for discussion like this. If you're having the same issue but don't know how to fix it, then you should click "Follow" (which appears right under this question) to get notifications when new answers are posted.

Answer (score 3):

I have a possible workaround.

1. Go to the settings of VS Code and search for "salesforcedx-vscode-apex".
2. Look for the Java: Home entry and paste the path of your Java jdk folder.
3. If you don't have Java installed, I recommend to download the newest 17 version. Use this path, for example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17`. Version 18 is not yet supported.

Comment: It worked for me. Apart from setting salesforcedx-vscode-apex > Java: Home, you will have to add same path to JAVA_HOME path variable for your system.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error in VSCode. It looks like it was due to jdk version issue. I changed to the Zulu JDK 17 from Zulu JDK 8 and it started to work.

Download Zulu JDK 17 (.zip) from [here](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&package=jdk#zulu) as per your operating system and exact it.

Please follow the below steps to resolve it.

1. Go to file -> Preferences -> Settings in vscode.
2. Click on workspace tab.
3. Search for Salesforce apex configuration and select the result.
4. Update Salesforcedx-vscode-apex value with the path of Zulu JDK you extracted.

Comment: I had to install java 17 and reset my Java home path to fix my VSC.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above is for MacOS.

**Instructions for MacOS**

1. Follow the official instructions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/vscode-desktop/java-setup)
2. After installing for example Zulu 17 for mac, go back to VS Code > Extensions Icon > Apex > Gear > Extension Settings
3. In Extension Settings, search for `Salesforcedx-vscode-apex`
4. If you use Zulu 17, replace the `JAVA_HOME` link with `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home`
5. If you want to use another Java JDK instead go Terminal and enter `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see which Java JDK you installed
6. Restart VS Code, Apex LSP should disappear

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2024 (Mac / Windows)**

In my case, none of the answers here solved the issue.

Probably because I reinstalled my laptop (Windows) and loaded the 'Apex Library' files in the `.sfdx` folder from my previous installation.

These instructions solved it for me:

*(removing the Apex Library and restarting VSCode to regenerate it)*
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/5251#issuecomment-1848425889